# Ubuntu rake aborted! NameError: uninitialized constant ActionDispatch::XmlParamsParser

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, redmine-plugins

I'm trying to install redmine's plugins on a machine with 16.04 ubuntu. Right now I'm trying to install agile plugin. I received the official documentation about how to install the plugin. I followed the step-by-step installation and I get stuck with an error.

**Important:**

I'm using Ruby 2.3.1.

**Steps**

1. Download and unzip on plugins folder
2. `cd /var/www/redmine` and `bundle install --without development test --no-deployment`
   (I got some errors here because of the mysql, nokogiri, and others gem.. but now it all ok)
3. `bundle exec rake redmine:plugins NAME=redmine_agile RAILS_ENV=production`

But every time I execute the previous command I receive this error:

> (in /usr/share/redmine) rake aborted! NameError: uninitialized
>   constant ActionDispatch::XmlParamsParser Did you mean? 
>   ActionDispatch::ParamsParser

Here is full log: (with trace)

> in /usr/share/redmine) rake aborted! NameError: uninitialized constant
>   ActionDispatch::XmlParamsParser Did you mean? 
>   ActionDispatch::ParamsParser
>   /usr/share/redmine/config/application.rb:55:in `<class:Application>'
>   /usr/share/redmine/config/application.rb:8:in`'
>   /usr/share/redmine/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
>   /usr/share/redmine/Rakefile:4:in`require'
>   /usr/share/redmine/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in`
>   load'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in
>   `load_rakefile'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:687:in`
>   raw_load_rakefile'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:96:in
>   `block in load_rakefile'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in`
>   standard_exception_handling'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in
>   `load_rakefile'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:79:in`
>   block in run'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in
>   `standard_exception_handling'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in`
>   run' /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top
>   (required)>' /usr/local/bin/rake:23:in`load'
>   /usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `<top (required)>'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in`
>   load'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in
>   `kernel_load'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in`
>   run'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:360:in
>   `exec'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in`
>   run'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in
>   `invoke_command'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:369:in`
>   dispatch'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in
>   `dispatch'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:444:in`
>   start'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:10:in
>   `start' /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/exe/bundle:35:in`
>   block in '
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:121:in
>   `with_friendly_errors'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/exe/bundle:27:in`' /usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
>   /usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in`'

I saw other post and i already try:

1. Change version: I have the last redmine version
2. `gem install actionpack-xml_parser`
3. Update Bundler
4. Execute rake on redmine root (i execute this on /var/www/html/redmine
5. And I saw some post on redmine dashboard to fix this error.. it was back on 2015.. I hope there are now some fix

**Structure**

I have my redmine installation on **/var/www/html/redmine** and my plugins on **/var/www/html/redmine/plugins**. I execute my commands on **/var/www/html/redmine**.

And if it is necessary here is my gem list:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (5.1.2, 4.2.9, 4.2.6)
actionpack (5.1.2, 4.2.9, 4.2.6)
actionpack-action_caching (1.2.0, 1.1.1)
actionpack-xml_parser (2.0.1, 1.0.2)
actionview (5.1.2, 4.2.9, 4.2.6)
activejob (5.1.2, 4.2.9, 4.2.6)
activemodel (5.1.2, 4.2.9, 4.2.6)
activerecord (5.1.2, 4.2.9, 4.2.6)
activesupport (5.1.2, 4.2.9, 4.2.6)
addressable (2.5.1, 2.3.8)
arel (8.0.0, 6.0.4, 6.0.3)
atomic (1.1.16)
awesome_nested_set (3.1.3, 3.0.0)
bigdecimal (1.2.8)
binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
blankslate (3.1.3)
builder (3.2.3, 3.2.2)
bundler (1.15.1, 1.11.2)
byebug (5.0.0)
coderay (1.1.1)
coffee-rails (4.2.2, 4.1.0)
coffee-script (2.4.1)
coffee-script-source (1.12.2, 1.9.1.1)
colored (1.2)
columnize (0.9.0)
concurrent-ruby (1.0.5)
connection_pool (2.2.1)
css_parser (1.5.0, 1.3.6)
debug_inspector (0.0.2)
did_you_mean (1.0.0)
erubi (1.6.1)
erubis (2.7.0)
eventmachine (1.0.7)
execjs (2.7.0, 2.6.0)
ffi (1.9.10)
gemrat (0.4.6)
globalid (0.4.0, 0.3.6)
hike (2.1.3, 1.2.1)
htmlentities (4.3.4, 4.3.3)
i18n (0.8.6, 0.7.0)
io-console (0.4.5)
jbuilder (2.7.0, 2.3.1)
jquery-rails (4.3.1, 4.0.5)
json (1.8.3)
listen (3.1.5, 3.0.3)
loofah (2.0.3)
mail (2.6.6, 2.6.3)
method_source (0.8.2)
mime-types (3.1, 2.6.1)
mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
mini_portile2 (2.2.0)
minitest (5.10.2, 5.8.4)
molinillo (0.5.7, 0.4.3)
multi_json (1.12.1, 1.11.2)
mysql2 (0.4.8, 0.4.3)
net-http-persistent (3.0.0, 2.9.4)
net-ldap (0.16.0, 0.8.0)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
nokogiri (1.8.0, 1.6.7.2)
oj (2.12.10)
polyglot (0.3.5, 0.3.4)
power_assert (1.0.2, 0.2.7)
protected_attributes (1.1.4, 1.1.3)
psych (2.0.17)
public_suffix (2.0.5)
rack (2.0.3, 1.6.8, 1.6.4)
rack-openid (1.4.2)
rack-test (0.7.0, 0.6.3)
rails (4.2.9, 4.2.6)
rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
rails-dom-testing (2.0.3, 1.0.8, 1.0.6)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
rails-observers (0.1.4, 0.1.2)
railties (5.1.2, 4.2.9, 4.2.6)
rake (12.0.0, 10.5.0)
rb-fsevent (0.10.2)
rb-inotify (0.9.10, 0.9.7)
rbpdf (1.19.2, 1.19.0)
rbpdf-font (1.19.1, 1.19.0)
rdoc (5.1.0, 4.2.1)
redcarpet (3.4.0, 3.3.4)
request_store (1.3.2, 1.3.0)
rmagick (2.16.0, 2.15.4)
roadie (3.2.2, 3.1.1)
roadie-rails (1.2.1, 1.1.0)
ruby-hmac (0.4.0)
ruby-openid (2.7.0)
ruby_dep (1.5.0)
sass (3.4.25, 3.4.21)
sass-rails (5.0.6, 5.0.4)
sdoc (0.4.2, 0.4.1)
spring (2.0.2, 1.3.6)
sprockets (3.7.1, 3.3.0)
sprockets-rails (3.2.0, 2.3.2)
sqlite3 (1.3.11)
test-unit (3.2.5, 3.1.7)
thor (0.19.4, 0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.6, 0.3.5)
tilt (2.0.7, 2.0.1)
treetop (1.6.8, 1.6.3)
turbolinks (5.0.1, 2.5.3)
turbolinks-source (5.0.3)
tzinfo (1.2.3, 1.2.2)
uglifier (3.2.0, 2.7.2)
web-console (2.2.1)
```

Comment: Did you try install redmine without plugins at first?

Comment: I have the same issue on Debian 9. I installed redmine through the Debian official package.

Answer (score 1):

I tried executing the same command from `/usr/share/redmine` instead of from the plugin's directory, and it worked for me. Before I had the same issue.

This was recommended in a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/a-ono/redmine_ckeditor/issues/226).